# Endwhile inesperado

Tags: php

```
<?php
 include "db.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Chat</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Vaani">
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="caja-chat">
            <div id="chat">
                <?php
                    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $ejecutar = $conexion->query($consulta);
                    while($fila = $ejecutar->fetch_array());
                ?>
                <div id="datos-chat">
                    <span style="color: #1c62c4;"><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>: </span>
                    <span style="color: #848484;"><?php echo $fila['mensaje']; ?></span>
                    <span style="float: right;"><?php echo $fila['fecha']; ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            <textarea name="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe mensaje"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Segun yo esta bien pero me da el error de **Syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE**
estoy tratando de crear un chat siguiendo este tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMlLgYyz_ws

Comment: Tienes un error en el `while(condicion)` es 2 puntos no punto y coma.

Comment: Como te comentan arriba y como aparece en el vídeo  que has puesto, el `while`  va con dos puntos final.  `while($fila = $ejecutar->fetch_array()):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta modificando el codigo asi:

```
            <div id="chat">
                <?php
                    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY id DESC";
                    $ejecutar = $conexion->query($consulta);
                    while($fila = $ejecutar->fetch_array()):
                echo '<div id="datos-chat">
                    <span style="color: #1c62c4;">'.$fila['nombre'].': </span>
                    <span style="color: #848484;">'.$fila['mensaje'].'</span>
                    <span style="float: right;">'.$fila['fecha'].'</span>
                </div>';
                endwhile;
               ?>
            </div>
```

Edito: como dijo el compañero en un comentario, pusiste en `while($fila = $ejecutar->fetch_array());` **punto y coma** en vez **de dos puntos** (Ya edite el codigo de la forma correcta con sus respectivos **dos puntos**)